# Lenovo Thinkpad issue

Tags: windows, windows-10, thinkpad, lenovo-laptop

I have a slight problem.

My Lenovo Thinkpad (unknown model as of now) will not boot up its Windows 10 OS. When I power it on, it has the Thinkpad logo, then it will go straight to a menu with two tabs. One of the options on the first tab is Windows Boot Manager, and that option doesn't work. It displays the other devices. I cannot get Windows to boot period.

I have tried reformatting it to Windows 7 Pro, but it won't allow me to do so. Does anyone have any answers?

I have run tests on the HDD from the Lenovo Diagnostics, and the HDD is perfectly fine.

https://lnv.i.lithium.com/t5/image/serverpage/image-id/109706i42693A1A85132A81/image-size/large?v=1.0&px=999

**This is an image I found on google that is similar to what I see**

Comment: Can you hit tab on the screen it boots to and run the Lenovo Diagnostics? Might be a failed drive.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Dial I have already ran test on the HDD. It s working fine

Comment: @EgMusic - Storage devices that are working fine, do not have boot problems, something isn't right with your storage device.

Comment: @Ramhound the HDD passed all the tests though. Could you clarify?

Comment: @EgMusic - in my 20 years of experience, I have never had a problem booting an OS, that wasn't related to the potential failure of a storage device.  Every single instance of an OS not being able to boot was directly linked, to that storage device in the process of failing.  The tests you ran are passing, but just because they pass, does not mean your HDD isn't about to fail.

Comment: You mention trying to install Win7, but have you tried Win10? Windows 10 should automatically activate without a serial if you held a valid license on that machine prior. Where exactly does it fail when you try to install Win7?

Comment: @Dial I'll get to the part where I get to organize my partitions, then I select my HDD (465GB), and it says I can't install it there. What can I do?

Comment: @Dial It will not let me install windows on my EMPTY (cause' I formatted it) HDD. Why does it no likey me?     :<

Comment: Honestly, it's likely that @Ramhound was correct with it being a bad drive. I've had Thinkpads refuse to image due to RAM issues, but as he mentioned, that's essentially just another "storage" device failure. The bad RAM was identified by the Lenovo diagnostics.

Comment: @Dial What can I do to confirm this? I have tried doing HDD, memory, and motherboard tests, but there didn't seem to be any problems.

Comment: @Dial I also have 4GB of RAM on my Thinkpad

Comment: Try a live CD that contains better disc health utilities, or try putting the drive in another computer (connected to motherboard or cheap USB adapter) and image. Isolate potential issues and rule them out as best you can and update your question accordingly.

Comment: @Dial A Windows CD?

Comment: @Dial A Windows CD?

Comment: No, probably a Linux live CD. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/59064/how-to-run-a-checkdisk#59077 do some reading, then update your question with what you try. Your question is too broad for anyone to venture a real answer without additional work on your part. I'm just attempting to give you avenues to narrow your question, I'm not Google. This is not a troubleshooting forum, it's a QA site.

Comment: @Dial where could I get to this, or what do I have to buy for it?